# Calculating the probability of someone doing something they want to do, but are afraid of doing

Tags: probability

I know this might sound like a stupid question, but I'll ask anyway.
How would someone go about calculating the probability of someone doing something they want to do, but are afraid of doing?
Like jumping out of a plane with a parachute.
Is this even possible?
I've googled this question, but the only thing I could find were motivational quotes. So I decided to ask you guys!

Now, I'm not really familiar with calculating probabilities. I just know you need to create a sample space from the given data and from there on it's just simple devision. But I can't find a way to create a sample space for this problem.

So please tell me. How can I go about solving this? Is it even possible to solve?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any way to turn this into a math problem, sorry.  It's far too subjective.  I don't want to eat Brussel Sprouts, but I almost certainly will at some point.  I also don't want to walk a tightrope and I can pretty much guarantee that I won't ever do it (not for more than one step anyway).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fear comes with low probability of success. That is why a calculation is at all  made. It is often necessary to estimate risk $ r = 1-p $, where  the probability level $p$ is accepted, we say the step taken has well-considered risks ..

In case of parachute or bungee jumping you need no direct calculation  (you came to this site expecting a quantified figure). But indirect checks of the operator's safety record, history, certification, reputation &c. of the plane, pilot and parachute equipment as satisfactory is needed.

There is no thrill without a small risk thrown in, that throws  fear out.